# What does "192-bit equivalent" mean for WPA3?

Tags: encryption, hmac, aes-gcm

In the Wikipedia page for WPA3 enterprise mode, it states that WPA3 has an "...equivalent 192-bit cryptographic strength in WPA3-Enterprise mode..." yet it also says that it uses AES-256-GCM with SHA-384 HMAC. How does the combination of these two yield 192 bit cryptographic strength? Shouldn't it be 256 bit strength?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access

Comment: It may be that the key agreement algorithm they use (Simultaneous Authentication of Equals) - and the parameters they use with that - has only 192 bits of security strength...

Answer (score 2):

The Wi-Fi Alliance has [more details about the cryptography used](https://www.wi-fi.org/discover-wi-fi/security):

> Extensible Authentication Protocol – Transport Layer Security (EAP-TLS) using Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman (ECDH) exchange and Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA) using a 384-bit elliptic curve

It's widely believed that using a secure 384-bit elliptic curve provides about 192 bits of strength.  An attacker who wanted to attempt a brute force would only need to exert $ 2^{192} $ effort to attack the ECDH key exchange rather than the 256 bits needed to brute force the AES-256 key derived from it.